# MVC disable field (read-only) based on the value of another

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik's product for MVC. I have a grid where two fields can be enabled or disabled based on the value of another field. The SetNextDueScheduleMethod field values can either be "Usage", "Date" or NULL. If the SetNextDueScheduleMethod = "Usage", then the SetNextDueDate should be disabled or read-only. If the SetNextDueScheduleMethod = "Date", then the SetNextDueUOM should be disabled or read-only.

I have a script that binds to the "OnEdit" event. I need assistance with the definition of the function "OnEdit" as the current code is not doing anything and not giving errors in the console:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMS.Models.ForecastItem>()
          .Name("grid")
          .Events(ev => ev.Edit("onEdit"))
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.FCI_text).Title("Description").Width(240);
              columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SetNextDueScheduleMethod, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ScheduleMethod"], "ScheduleMethodID", "ScheduleMethodID")
                     .Title("Next Due Schedule Method").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)).Width(180);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SetNextDueUOM).Width(180);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SetNextDueDate).Format("{0: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}").Width(180);
              columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(230);
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 720px;" })
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              toolbar.Excel();
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Pageable()
          .Navigatable()
          .Sortable(sortable =>
          {
              sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
          })
          .Filterable()
          .Scrollable()
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(500)
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.FCI_ID);
                  model.Field(p => p.FCI_ID).Editable(false);
              })
              .Read(read => read.Action("ForecastItems_Read", "ForecastItem"))
              .Update(update => update.Action("ForecastItems_Update", "ForecastItem"))
              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ForecastItems_Destroy", "ForecastItem"))
          )
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onEdit(e) {
        if (e.model.SetNextDueScheduleMethod == "Usage") {
            $(e.container).find('input[name="SetNextDueDate"]').attr("disabled", true);
          //  $("[name='SetNextDueDate']").enable(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is `onEdit` called at all, e.g. can you break execution with the `debugger` keyword?

Comment: It could be it's working fine and the if statement inside `onEdit` is returning false. I agree with @KaiHartmann, you should add `debugger` to the function and step through it.